# Add active class on changing slide - swiper js

Tags: swiper.js

I have the following markup. What should I do to add active class to the corresponding name in  link when I change the slide using drag and drop? Slides are dynamic and it can be more than 2.

```
<div class="names">
  <a id="slide0" class="job-name active">First elem</a>
  <a id="slide1" class="job-name">Second elem</a>
</div>

<div class="swiper mySwiper">
 <div class="swiper-wrapper">
   
        <div class="swiper-slide">First slide</div>
         <div class="swiper-slide">Second slide</div>
   
        </div>
      
      </div>
      
       <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
       <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>

 <link
  rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256- 
pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script>
  var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 50,
    centeredSlides: true,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: false,
    navigation: {
       nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
       prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
  });

  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.job-name').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     jQuery('.job-name').not(jQuery(this)).removeClass('active');
     jQuery(this).addClass('active');
   })

   jQuery('#slide0').on('click', swiper, function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     swiper.slideTo(1);
   })
  
   jQuery('#slide1').on('click', swiper, function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    swiper.slideTo(2);
  })
  
 })
 </script>
```